# How to access a jwt token from a django rest framework to angular frontend

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, jwt, frontend

I have created a DRF api authenticated with jwt,the token is stored in a cookie.I can successfully access all the viewsets using the token with postman.It only becomes a problem when l want to pass the token to angular frontend for the same operations.I am using django rest framework backend and Angular 9 frontend.Also note that l am storing the token in a cookie.

**My views.py**

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    
    def post(self,request):
        #getting the inputs from frontend/postman
        email =request.data['email']
        password =request.data['password']
        
        user=User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
        #Authentication
        if user is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found!')

        if user.password!=password :
            raise AuthenticationFailed("incorrect password")

        payload = {
            'id':user.id,
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10),
            'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        }

        token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
        
        response = Response()
        #storing the token in a cookie
        response.set_cookie(key='jwt',value=token ,httponly=True)
        response.data = {
            'jwt':token
        }
        return response

class UserView(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        token=request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
        
        if not token:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("unauthorised")
        
        try:
            payload =jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("session expired")

        user=User.objects.get(id=payload['id'])
        
        serializer=UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class Update(APIView):
      def get_object(self,request):
            try:
                token=request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
                
                if not token:
                    raise AuthenticationFailed("unauthorised")
                
                try:
                    payload =jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
                except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
                    raise AuthenticationFailed("session expired")

                user=User.objects.get(id=payload['id'])
                
                return user

            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return Response("wakadhakwa",status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

      def get(self,request):
            obj=self.get_object(request)
            serializer=UserSerializer(obj)
            return Response(serializer.data)


      def put(self,request):
        
        obj=self.get_object(request)
        serializer=UserSerializer(obj,data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response("corrupted data",status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

      def delete(self,request):
        all=self.get_object(request)  
        all.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the cookie gets properly saved in browser when receiving response from login?

Are you calling the UserView endpoints from your Angular app with an AJAX call or are you reloading the page? If it is a call from the app make sure that the request sends cookies. It depends on how exactly you request the data, e.g. if you're using fetch, then make sure you have the option `credentials: 'include'` set. If you're requesting the data in some other way try to find in the documentation which option is used to enable sending credentials (cookies).

Comment: I am using ```  this.dataService.login(this.form.value).subscribe((res)=>{
        
        localStorage.setItem("token",res.jwt)
    } ```                                                                                                                                        
   to store the token in the local storage

Comment: This sets the token in the local storage, but you also set in a cookie, and in your endpoints you read it from a cookie, so setting it in local storage is redundant. Can you show the Angular code which you use to call e.g. `UserView.get`?